# Python LEGB lookup

Tags: python, function, scope

I think I have misunderstood Python LEGB lookup principle. So, at first just hear my understanding.

If python interpreter encounters a variable name it at first looks for it in **L**ocal scope, if not found then in **E**nclosing scope, if still not found then in **G**lobal and if not found then at last in **B**uiltin scope.

It behaves as such for the following code:

```
x = 10
def myfunc():
    print(x)
```

Running `myfunc` function will print out 10. Python finds the variable x in Global scope.

But problem arises for the following code:

```
x = 10
def myfunc():
    x = x * 2
    print(x)
```

Now running `myfunc` function will cause `UnboundLocalError`.
Why can't python interpreter utilise the LEGB lookup here and print `20`?
I know that in assignment statements python evaluates the right side expression at first. So, here python should search for x, find it in global scope, evaluate the expression `x * 2` and attach the name `x` for this value `20`.
I am surely missing some simple points here.

Comment: That is because `x = `  in myfunc telling python to define a new variable in the local scope with same name as global? Try changing the variable name to y in myfunc

Comment: try to define your function with positional argument. eg:  def myfunc(x):

Answer (score 1):

For:

```py
x = 10
def myfunc():
    print(x)
```

The interpreter cannot find an instance of `x` declared within the function, so looks up to the next layer, finds `x = 10` and uses that.

In the case of:

```py
x = 10
def myfunc():
    x = x * 2
    print(x)
```

The `x =`  command indicates that you are declaring a **new** variable `x` within the function.  Then, the `x * 2` says to take a variable `x` and multiply it by 2.  Since you have an `x` declared in the local scope, the interpreter will use that version of `x`, but it's not given a value until `x * 2` is evaluated, therefore an exception is raised.